# Angular material pagination stay on current page on reload or when we route back from another page

Tags: angular

HTML -

```
<div class="mat-table__bottom">
                <mat-paginator #paginator [length]="totalLength" [pageSize]="page_size" [pageSizeOptions]="[10]"
                    (page)="pageEvent = $event; changePage($event)" showFirstLastButtons>
                </mat-paginator>
            </div>
```

TS -

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.loadList(this.page, this.page_size, this.search);
  }

 ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
  }

 loadList(page, page_size, search) {
    this.userService.getList(page, page_size, search)
      .subscribe((res: any) => {
        this.totalLength = res.body.data.count;
        this.data = res.body.data;
        this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(res.body.data.rows);
        this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
        this.cd.detectChanges();
      }
  }

changePage(event: PageEvent) {
    this.page = event.pageIndex;
    this.page_size = event.pageSize;
    this.page = this.page + 1;
    this.loadList(this.page, this.page_size, this.search)
  }
```

When we route to another page and get back to this list page, it should not reset to first page. Or when we reload the page it should not reset to first page.
How can we can we do that?

Comment: did you try keeping the current state of the pagination on a service ?

Comment: @Buzzinga that will not work on a reload. 
You can add the page as a queryparameter

Comment: @Alexander yea, I missed the "reload" part.

Comment: @Alexander But if I send the page in queryParams and suppose move to page 3 then onreload/changePage the queryParams does not gets updated.